# Python Flask wt forms ventilator check if password is matching database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I am trying to create a from where before updating records the user must type in their password for validation.

I was thinking of useing something like this.

```
class AccountSettingsForm(Form):
        password_proof= TextField("Password:",[validators.EqualTo(current_user.password, message='Passwords Invlaid')])
```

But i get this error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a validator method with the syntax `validate_{field_name}`. Also, as you are using other data (the user instance, which contains their password), you need to initialize the form with that user instance.

Something like this should work for your example:

```
from wtforms import ValidationError

class AccountSettingsForm(Form):
    password_proof= TextField("Password:")

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def validate_password_proof(self, field):
        if field.data != self.user.password:
            raise ValidationError('Wrong password.')
```

Then, when initializing the form, you need to do it like this:

```
form = AccountSettingsForm(current_user)
```

On an unrelated side note, you should encrypt your users' passwords if you are not doing so.